# What algebraic structures are related to the McGee graph?

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups

Recall that an $(n,g)$-graph is a simple graph where each node has $n$ neighbors and the shortest cycle has length $g$, while an $(n,g)$-cage is $(n,g)$-graph with the minimum number of nodes.

The McGee graph is the unique $(3,7)$-cage.  It looks like this:

[image: McGee graph]

Now, the unique $(3,6)$-cage is the Heawood graph, which has [strong connections to the Fano plane and its symmetry group](http://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2015/08/01/heawood-graph/), $PGL(3,\mathbb{F}_2)$.  The unique $(3,8)$-cage is the Tutte–Coxeter graph, which has [strong connections to the Cremona–Richmond configuration and its symmetry group](http://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2015/08/15/tutte-coxeter-graph/), $S_6$.  These stories are fascinating and strongly parallel.

What about the McGee graph?  All I know is what I read:

- [McGee graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McGee_graph), Wikipedia.

It has 24 nodes and 36 edges.  Its symmetry group has 32 elements — which 32-element group is it?  Its symmetry group doesn't act transitively on the nodes: there are two orbits, containing 16 and 8 nodes.

Is this graph associated to an interesting finite geometry, or not?

Comment: The Heawood and T/C graphs are both bipartite so there is an obvious geometric interpretation by taking the two parts to be "points" and "lines". The McGee graph is not bipartite, so any geometric connection will be more hidden.

Comment: The group is not a super-interesting group, it is SmallGroup(32,43) in either GAP or Magma, described as $(C_2 \times D_8) : C_2$. The standard picture of the McGee graph shows an 8-fold rotation hence the dihedral group, and presumably the other two $C_2$s can be seen in the picture.

Comment: +Gordon - how did you figure out this symmetry group?  According to http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Holomorph_of_Z8 , SmallGroup(32,43) is the semidirect product of Z/8 with its automorphism group.

Comment: Alternatively, SmallGroup(32,43) is the 'general affine group' $\mathrm{GA}(1,\mathbb{Z}/8)$ of the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}/8$ meaning the group of all invertible transformations of the form $x \mapsto ax + b$

Comment: So, it's possible that we could create the McGee graph starting with the geometry of the affine line over $\mathbb{Z}/8$.  The general affine group acts on the vertices of the McGee graph with two orbits: one of size 8 and one of size 16.  It might make sense to take the 8 to be the points of the affine line (that is, points of $\mathbb{Z}/8$).

Comment: John, the description is just what GAP produces from the function "StructureDescription", and will rarely be unique. I don't understand the wiki statement that it is the general affine group because surely $AGL(1,8)$ has $8 \times 7 = 56$ elements?

Comment: Thanks!  So you handed GAP the McGee graph and told it to compute its symmetry group?

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}/8$ has just 4 invertible elements: 1, 3, 5 and 7.  So, $\mathbb{Z}/8$ has $8 \times 4$ invertible transformations of the form $x \mapsto ax + b$.

Comment: I got the automorphism group from another program (many will do it) but then used GAP to get its structure.

Comment: One naïve approach just occurred to me - look at vector realizations of the graphic matroid of the McGee graph; or, if it is too big to handle, try picking some length and cutting down to matroids with all cycles of this length as circuits. For example, cycles of length 9 seem promising in view of Greg Egan's answer.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Genus 2 embedding of McGee graph]

**Edited 27 September 2016**

(An earlier version of this answer incorrectly claimed to show that the genus of the McGee graph was 3.  **In fact, the genus of the McGee graph is 2.**  Thanks to Gordon Royle, who pointed out this mistake.)

The image above shows how to embed the McGee graph into a surface of genus 2.  There are 10 oriented cycles here (8 of length 7, and 2 of length 8) which contain each edge twice with opposite orientations.  So the Euler characteristic of the oriented surface in which the graph is embedded here is $\chi=24-36+10=-2$, and its genus is $g=2$.

We can prove that this is the minimum genus as follows:

Suppose we've embedded the graph in an orientable surface, so that the surface is decomposed into $F$ regions.  These regions might not all be simply connected, so in general we will say that each has $b_i$ connected components to its boundary, and the $j$th connected component of the boundary of the $i$th region is comprised of $n_{i,j}$ edges of the graph, forming a cycle of the graph.

Since each of the 36 edges of the graph appears twice in these boundaries, we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^F \sum_{j=1}^{b_i} n_{i,j} = 2 \times 36 = 72$$

But the smallest cycles in the graph have length 7, so:

$$7 \sum_{i=1}^F b_i \le 72$$

Since the $b_i$ are integers, it follows that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^F b_i \le 10$$

If the total number of holes in all the regions is $H$, we have:

$$F + H = \sum_{i=1}^F b_i \le 10$$

A division of the surface into $F$ regions with a total of $H$ holes can be converted into a division into $F$ *simply connected* regions by adding $H$ additional edges, without changing the number of vertices (e.g. an annulus can be converted into a disk by adding one edge).  Counting these $H$ supplementary edges in addition to the $E$ edges of the graph, we have the Euler characteristic for an orientable surface of genus $g$:

$$V - (E+H) + F = 24 - 36 + F - H = 2 - 2g$$
$$g = 7 - \frac{1}{2}(F-H)$$

But we have:

$$F-H = F+H-2H \le 10-2H$$
$$g \ge 2+H$$

So the genus of the surface must be at least 2, and $g=2$ is only possible when $H=0$ and the surface is divided into $F=10$ simply connected regions.

There is also a nice, symmetrical embedding of this graph into a surface of genus 3:

[image: Dissection of McGee graph into 8 nonagons]

The image above shows 8 oriented 9-gons, arranged so that pairs of oppositely-oriented edges from different 9-gons form the edges of the McGee graph.  So the Euler characteristic of the oriented surface in which the graph is embedded here is $\chi=24-36+8=-4$, and its genus is $g=3$.

Any dihedral symmetry of the original planar embedding of the graph just permutes these eight 9-gons among themselves.  The other graph automorphisms give different 9-gons on the planar embedding, for example:

[image: Dissection of McGee graph into 8 different nonagons]

The Riemann surface for the genus 3 embedding looks like this:

[image: Riemann surface of genus 3 from McGee graph]

where edges and faces with the same numbers should be identified.  The complete symmetry group of this surface is the 16-element dihedral group, with the orientation-preserving symmetries giving an 8-element cyclic subgroup.

Comment: Does this embedding preserve some of the symmetry of the graph?

Comment: @Will Sawin:  I don't understand exactly what you're asking.  Does it entail putting a metric on the surface, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I just want to know if there are automorphisms of the surface that send the graph to the graph and act on the graph as one of the 32 automorphisms in its automorphism group. Automorphisms in the topological category are fine.

Comment: @WillSawin At least I think the 45° rotation of this picture encodes a self-homeomorphism of the surface: if one maps the 9-gons homeomorphically to each other according to the rotation, incidences will match, so this should give a well-defined homeomorphism of the whole thing.

Comment: A 180° rotation around any of the four axes of symmetry will also map 9-gons to 9-gons, so you can get the full 16-element $D_8$ subgroup.  The other 16 elements of the graph automorphism group don't preserve the 9-gon structure on the graph, which makes it harder to see whether or not there are homeomorphisms of the surface that act on the graph as those automorphisms.

Comment: I've added an image that shows the effect on the 9-gons of one of the non-$D_8$ symmetries. Although these are a different set of eight 9-gons in the planar embedding, by the nature of graph isomorphisms all incidence relations between the 9-gons are preserved.

Comment: Found what seems to be a picture of this map [on "weddslist.com"](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/genus/3/9-3/9-3.php)

Comment: I've done some computer calculations to rule out any genus 2 embedding, so the genus of the graph appears to be exactly 3.

Comment: In principle it is also possible to draw a graph on a surface in such a way that some areas are not simply connected. For example, there is a genus 3 embedding of the McGee graph with eight heptagons and one polygonal annulus bordered by two disjoint octagons. I am in doubt whether such embeddings count in the definition of the genus, but still - can one rule them out?

Comment: I've now dealt with the possibility that the embedding of the graph divides the surface into regions that might not all be simply connected.  The result still holds:  the genus of the surface must be at least 3.

Comment: Correction - the link to a picture that I provided earlier is for a different graph. Although it shows a genus 3 map with eight 9-gons meeting 3 at a vertex, the graph has 4-cycles, so it is not the McGee graph.

Comment: Are you sure? The embedding I mentioned two comments above looks suspiciously similar, having the same numbers of faces, but one of the faces is not simply connected, so the Euler characteristic formula needs a correction in this case and one gets 3.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer, only an illustration.
I tried to find a maximally symmetric embedding into 3-space.

It might be viewed as an embedding into a solid torus, with two disjoint 8-cycles on the surface and 8 vertices in four $\boldsymbol\rangle\!\!\!\boldsymbol-\!\!\!\boldsymbol\langle$-like shapes inside the torus.

Motion realizes an automorphism of order 8 (image of the embedding coincides with itself after every $\frac\pi2$-turn; after $2\pi$ one gets a nontrivial involution).

$\ \hskip8em \ $[image]

Many thanks to Simon Rose for immediately noticing that my first attempt was obviously rubbish.

Comment: That can't be the same graph; it has several cycles of length 4.

Comment: Oops you are right

Comment: I will stop this for a while :D

Comment: Corrected (four days ago actually, it just occurred to me that I should say it here)

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე - I'm trying to send you an email to ask if I can use your animation on blog, crediting you.  When I send email to  mamuka.jibladze@rmi.ge or jib@rmi.acnet.ge, it bounces back to me.

Comment: Oh yes and probably you should also mention that it was made using Mathematica

Comment: By the way - if you want to delete your email addresses now that I have them, go ahead.  It may reduce your spam slightly.  Know, however, that the email address on your webpage does not work, nor does the one on your most recent published paper.

Comment: @JohnBaez Good idea. And thanks for pointing out outdated emails, have to correct it

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Gordon Royle's help, Greg Egan and I were able to work out some of the algebraic structures related to the McGee graph.  I explained them here:

- John Baez, [The McGee graph](http://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2015/09/15/mcgee-graph/), *Visual Insight*, 15 September 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting work. Is genus of this graph known? Or generally any nice non-self-intersecting embeddings in some surface?

Comment: Wikipedia says "The McGee graph requires at least eight crossings in any drawing of it in the plane. It is one of five non-isomorphic graphs tied for being the smallest cubic graph that requires eight crossings. Another of these five graphs is the generalized Petersen graph G(12,5), also known as the Nauru graph."  Does this tell you the genus of the graph?  Maybe there's a nice Riemann surface you can draw the McGee graph on, with the McGee symmetry group $\mathrm{GA}(1,\mathbb{Z}/8)$ acting as conformal transformations.

Comment: Seems like Nauru graph can be [very nicely drawn on a torus](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Symmetric_group_4%3B_Cayley_graph_1%2C5%2C21_%28Nauru_torus%29.svg) but what does this tell about the McGee graph?

Answer (score 3):

certainly Sage(math) can easily compute the structure of this group:

```
sage: g=graphs.McGeeGraph()
sage: a=g.automorphism_group()    
sage: a.structure_description()
'(C2 x D4) : C2'
```

(Sage makes an unusual choice to denote the dihedral group $D_{2k}$ of order $2k$ as $D_k$...)

Comment: [edited just to fix a transparent typo]

Comment: That is a very odd choice because as far as I can tell, the structure_description() command is pushed off to GAP, which uses $D_{2k}$.

Comment: if k is odd it becomes truly odd :) Well, there are books making this choice, although no modern finite group theory papers do so, IMHO.